# How to convert HTML to PDF using pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Which libraries do I need? 
Which command line parameters do I need to pass?

I've installed wkhtml2pdf and 
I've tried to run:

`pandoc reports/7/report.html -t pdf -o reports/7/report.pdf`

Which reports an error of:

```
To create a pdf with pandoc, use the latex or beamer writer and specify
an output file with .pdf extension (pandoc -t latex -o filename.pdf).
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pdf` is not a valid output format. `latex` and `beamer` (for latex slideshows) are.

To create a pdf, use `-t latex` and `-o myoutput.pdf`. You can omit the `-t` argument since a `.pdf` in `-o` defaults to latex. So you can use either:

```
pandoc reports/7/report.html -t latex -o reports/7/report.pdf
```

or:

```
pandoc reports/7/report.html -o reports/7/report.pdf
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work - it converts it to plain text..when I try to open the result with a document viewer, I get: `File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported`

Comment: I think this is what's needed `echo foo | pandoc -t latex | pdflatex  >  ./test.pdf`  but I still get the `text/plain is not supported`

Answer (score 12):

From https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html:

> Alternatively, pandoc can use any of the following HTML/CSS-to-PDF-engines, to create a PDF:
>
> - [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)
> - [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/)
> - [prince](https://www.princexml.com/)
>
> To do this, specify an output file with a .pdf extension, as before, but add the **--pdf-engine** option or -t context, -t html, or -t ms to the command line (**-t html** defaults to **--pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf**).

Comment: on Windows I did `choco install wkhtmltopdf` to get that pdf-engine.  Then you can specify with `--pdf-engine wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: If you have one of these installed, do you even need pandoc?

Comment: Keep in mind `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't support Javascript ES6, `weasyprint` doesn't support Javascript at all and `prince` does support these modern JS but based on their forum & docs, it's not 100%.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ -o pep8.pdf
```

You need to have a LaTeX distribution installed such as [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

If you want to color the links, you should add `linkcolors` options. If the webpage contains CJK characters, you need to specify `CJKmainfont` options. An example is shown below:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V colorlinks -V CJKmainfont="KaiTi" https://jdhao.github.io/2019/01/07/windows_tools_for_programmers/ -o programmer_tools.pdf
```

The font `KaiTi` supports Chinese characters. If you use other languages, you may use the `mainfont` option to specify a font which supports the language the webpage uses.

If the webpage contains svg images, you also need to install [rsvg-convert](https://chocolatey.org/packages/rsvg-convert) to successfully convert the webpage to PDF files (see reference [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/265)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't get math formula well with this method. It will not compile the latex command in the html. So how do you solve this problem.

Comment: which link are you trying to convert to pdf? Post the link.

Answer (score 3):

For me, running linux with pandoc 1.19.2.4, (and converting `cv.md`) I needed to use:

```
pandoc -t html5 -o cv.pdf cv.md
```

the 5 in `html5` seems to be missing from a lot of things I have Googled.

Please note that you need `wkhtmltopdf` installed for this to work.